# NumberDecimalSeparator not showing the correct value as specified in Number Formatting in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I have the following problem that has me stumped. I have recently installed a fresh Windows 8 machine after having this code working before on Windows 7. (Not sure if its related)

```
Console.Write(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator);
```

When running through the code checking the NumberDecimalSeparator of the Current Culture Info it shows a comma instead of a decimal point.

When looking at the Number Formatting screen in Windows settings it is definitely set to a decimal place.

Could this be an issue with .Net 4.5 and Windows 8?

Comment: I can't repeat the problem on Win8/.NET 4.5. When I change the setting, the output changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this to work.

I set the Application Pool Identity to NetworkService and it now works. However on another machine that had the same issue I had to set it to LocalSystem to get it to work so I am not too sure if this is a proper resolution.